# Which is correct - were or was?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subjunctives

The sentence reads:

> However, if we were great friends with someone who committed murder or robbed a store, we wouldn’t question whether murder or stealing **were bad**.

Is this correct or should it be "was bad"?

I feel since he used "or" it should be "was". If he had used "and", then "were" would be correct. I'm just not sure.

Comment: Hint: Look up "subjucntive mood" online.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The question is not about mood, but subject-verb agreement.

Comment: Googling **singular or plural after or** offers this:  When two or more singular nouns or pronouns are connected by or or nor, use a singular verb. The book or the pen is in the drawer. 3. When a compound subject contains both a singular and a plural noun or pronoun joined by or or nor, the verb should agree with the part of the subject that is nearer the verb.  
Purdue Online Writing Lab
https://owl.purdue.edu › owl › subject_verb_agreement